# "You have requested a non-existent service 'callable_resolver'"

Tags: updating, 10

When I update from Drupal 10.1.7 to Drupal 10.2, the website doesn't work anymore and shows the following error message.

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested
> a non-existent service "callable_resolver". Did you mean this: class_resolver"?
> in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get()
> (line 157 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php).

I don't have any idea on how to solve this.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: That looks like a new service: https://www.drupal.org/node/3368504 Did you complete all upgrade steps including running update.php?

Comment: Thank you so much Cilefen, I didn't run update.php. Now everything looks fine!!